# Partition of a set in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Why
$$
E=(E\backslash E')\cup E'
$$
isn't true in general? I don't see. $\text{Thank you very much}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that would assume $E' \subset E$, which isn't always true. Consider $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology and $E = (0,1)$. Then $E' = [0,1]$.

Comment: So simple. Feel bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw a Venn Diagram (then it will also be clear under which conditions that assertion holds)

Comment: So if I draw Venn Diagram then $E$ is divided into $E\backslash E'$ and $E'$ because $E'$ is in $E$. But wrong?